# factorial for large numbers giving wrong output

Tags: c++, stl, factorial

> I am trying to find the factorial of large numbers
>
> I input t number of test cases
>
> and a number in each case whose factorial I am trying to find
>
> I am storing the digits of the factorial in a vector (dynamic array)
>
> and multiplying it each time with decremented n's value
>
> function display: displays all digits in vector v

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void display(vector<int> v)
{
    for(int x : v)
    {
        cout << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


vector <int> factorial(int n)
{
    vector <int>v;
    if(n > 9)
    {
        int n1 = n;
        int r;
        while(n1 != 0)
        {
            r = n1 % 10;
            n /= 10;
            v.insert(v.begin(), r);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        v.push_back(n);
    }
    --n;
    int pdt;
    int carry = 0;
    int digit;

    while(n != 1)
    {
        for(int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            pdt = v[i] * n + carry;
            carry = pdt / 10;
            digit = pdt % 10;
            v.insert(v.begin() + i, digit);
            // display(v);
        }
        if(carry != 0)
        {
            if(carry > 9)
            {
                int n1 = n;
                int r;
                while(n1 != 0)
                {
                    r = n1 % 10;
                    n /= 10;
                    v.insert(v.begin(), r);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                v.insert(v.begin(), carry);
            }
            
        }
        carry = 0;
        --n;
    }

    return v;  
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin >>n;
        vector <int> v;
        v = factorial(n);
        display(v);
    }
}
```

> output for n = 5

```
1264221101505
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did try to use GDB .. and what I found was that my vector was giving me junk values .. I did not understand that behaviour ...hence I asked this question

Comment: "Junk values" means either uninitialized memory usage, or the calculations are wrong. In either case, that's something you can determine with `gdb`, as well.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental flaw in your algorithm. The first thing you do is push `5` onto the vector. At no point do you remove or modify this value so your output is going to contain `5` but the correct output is `120`.

Comment: An issue at the beginning of `factorial`: it should be `n1 \= 10;` and not `n\= 10`;`

Comment: A small tip: Pass a reference of your vector in the main to the factorial function instead of returning one from it and pass a const reference to your display function. This will speed up the code.

Comment: @ArdentCoder A meaningful performance improvement would be to use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: At the begging of display function there's a error in the looping for:   `for( int x : v )`  Didn't you mean something like this`x > v`?

Comment: @d.olinger That's a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Haha @Kerndog73 I was just trying to introduce references and performance boost to the OP

Comment: @d.olinger C++ has evolved a lot since the addition of C++11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues in the code. The main one is that the current vector is never modified: each time a new digit is found, it is inserted. There was also the issue of having one variable used instead of another one.

Moreover, the code could be greatly simplified with the convention that `v[0]` corresponds to the LSB and not the MSB.

There was also the possibility to simplify the code by avoiding useless tests, as `if (n > 9 ....)`.

Here is a working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void display (std::vector<int> &v) {
    for (int i = v.size() -1 ; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::cout << v[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

std::vector<int> factorial (int n) {
    std::vector<int> v; 
    v.push_back(1);

    while (n != 1) {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            int pdt = v[i] * n + carry;
            carry = pdt / 10;
            v[i] = pdt % 10;
        }
        while (carry != 0) {
            int r = carry % 10;
            carry /= 10;
            v.push_back(r);
        }
        --n;
    }
    return v;  
}

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        auto v = factorial(n);
        display(v);
    }
}
```